# how to download application Statistics data from google developer console using gsutil?

Tags: gsutil

I have used Gsutil to download the Ratings and reviews data, Earnings and Sales report data with following comment 
gsutil cp -r gs://pubsite_prod_rev_/reviews/* ~/gsutil/output/

Now I m trying with Application Statistics Data. But don't know how Please tell me if you anybody Knows.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using http://graboto.com and you don't have to bother with gsutil.

Answer (score 0):

For all reviews use:

```
gsutil cp -r gs://pubsite_prod_rev_xxxxxxxx/reviews ./download
```

For all stats use:

```
gsutil cp -r gs://pubsite_prod_rev_xxxxxxxx/stats ./download
```

For single application use:

```
gsutil cp -r gs://pubsite_prod_rev_xxxxxxxx/reviews/reviews_your_package_name* ./download
```

For single application for specified month use:

```
gsutil cp -r gs://pubsite_prod_rev_xxxxxxxx/reviews/reviews_your_package_name_201506 ./download
```